# Regex matching with two substrings in "OR" condition

Tags: python-3.x

The problem I have in hand is that I have to pick out all the table names from a given SQL statement. Since all table names will have a schema in the statements that are provided I am thinking of creating a regex pattern like

```
from[ ]+[a-z,1-9,_]+[.][a-z,1-9,_]+
```

and

```
join[ ]+[a-z,1-9,_]+[.][a-z,1-9,_]+
```

Now I want to combine the two regex pattern into something like "[from|join]". However [from|join] starts matching strings starting with "m/n". I tried to used named groups, but was unsuccessful with that. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question is to use an alternation:

```
(?:from|join)[ ]+[a-z,1-9,_]+[.][a-z,1-9,_]+
```

What you mentioned above, `[from|join]`, does not mean match `from` or `join`, but rather it means to match anyone of the characters appearing inside the character class (`f`, `i`, `j`, `m`, `n`, `o`, `r`).